# Using Coroutine for continuous data polling and dumping to UI

Tags: android, android-studio, android-asynctask, kotlin-coroutines, kotlin-flow

My existing Android code uses `AsyncTask` to continuously poll data from a **virtual COM** port and dumps data to UI thread by overriding the `onProgressUpdate()` function. Something like the following:

```
open class ComActivity(deviceID:Int, listener: OnComRxUpdateUI) : AsyncTask<..., ..., ...>(){
  ...   
  override fun doInBackground(...) { 
  ...   //keep listening on serial port and transfer byte to buffer when available
  }

  override fun onProgressUpdate(...){
  ...  //dump to ui 
  }  
}
```

The above code works fine (except for some memory leak warnings here and there).

Every now and then, I see `Coroutine` being promoted for performing concurrent, and asynchronous operations, and I find compelled to try replacing `AsyncTask` with Coroutine. OTOH, I do not fully grasp the working of `Coroutines` as a substitute for `AsyncTask`. So my question is whether `Coroutine` is a **viable** replacement for my use case (continuous data polling and dumping on UI). Any good high-level (or pseudo) example
out there that demonstrate this use case are welcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is hard to assume how you are listening on a serial port in `AsyncTask`, whether you use some kind of listener or an infinite loop, but I guess the same result can be achieved using [`Flow`](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/flow.html#flows) and `MVVM` approach. It will look something like the following:

In Repository class:

```
fun listenPort(): Flow<String> = flow {
    // keep listening on serial port, use emit() function to emit data
    while (true) {
        val data = listen()
        emit(data)
    }
}

suspend fun listen() = withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
    // listening on serial port
}
```

In `ViewModel`:

```
private val _state = MutableStateFlow<State>(Loading)
val state = _state

init {
    repository.listenPort()
        .onEach { data ->
            _state.value = Dump(data)
        }.launchIn(viewModelScope)
}
```

States:

```
sealed interface State
object Loading : State
data class Dump(val data: ...) : State
```

In Ui(`Activity` or `Fragment`):

```
vm.state
        .flowWithLifecycle(lifecycle)
        .onEach { state ->
            // handle all states
            if (state is Dump) {
                val data = state.data
                // use data
            }
    }.launchIn(lifecycleScope)
```

---

If you are not a fan of the approach of using `MVVM` architecture, you can do all of it in UI class(`Activity` or `Fragment`), which I don't recommend:

```
listenPort().flowWithLifecycle(lifecycle)
        .onEach { data ->
            // use data
        }.launchIn(lifecycleScope)
```

Comment: Thank you, I appreciate this detailed answer. I am going to try this. At the moment, I am not able to organize these modules (MVVM) into a working code. To begin with, I think it will be easier to try the last (albeit not recommended) snippet cause it seems to be concise and in one place only. Please feel free to point to any good resources on the MVVM approach.

Comment: "It is hard to assume how you are listening on a serial port in AsyncTask, whether you use some kind of listener or an infinite loop"    I am using an **infinite loop** inside the `AsyncTask`.

Comment: I forgot to add an implementation for the `listen()` method. Please check my edited answer. Basically it should run in `Dispatchers.IO` context to listen on the port in background thread.